How to use mininet with Linux taprio to simulate TSN's TAS? Is the language Python?
Can mininet and taprio be combined to simulate TSN's tas mechanism, cqf mechanism, and DetNet's csqf mechanism. And is it open source? Mininet version 2.2 and later can be used with taprio. Does it have its own TAS simulation function like NeSTiNg, or do you need to manually integrate the taprio function of Linux? If it is integrated rather than internally embedded, are these open source and easy to integrate?
Which one is easier to get started with mininet or NeSTiNg? If you don’t want to learn C++, python can be used

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I don't work yet on this topic but i will give you a paper that maybe can help you. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9657100. Good luck
